# Сколько живут cookie, если явно не задавать срок жизни?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, cookie

**Теоретически**, если не задать явно время жизни `cookie`, она должна жить, пока жив экземпляр браузера (пока не будут закрыты все окна и вкладки).

**Практически** Открываю информацию в браузере(*google chrome*) и вижу:
`JSEESIONID` -  `Expires/Max-age` - **1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z**

**P.S.** Пишу *Web Project* на *сервлетах* и *jsp*. Как только создаю `сессию` пользователя, `cookie` автоматически включается в ответ пользователю.

Что происходит? Закрытие браузера, всех окон и вкладок, в том числе в диспетчере задач, всё это не убивает cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Цитата](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

> A session is finished when the client is shut down meaning that
>   session cookies will get removed at that point. However, many web
>   browsers have a feature called session restore that will save all your
>   tabs and have them come back next time you use the browser. Cookies
>   will also be present and it's like you had never actually closed the
>   browser.

Отключите в своём браузере автоматическое восстановление сессии и ваш `JSEESIONID` будет удаляться после перезапуска.

Comment: Спасибо, все так